# This LUA code has an end error that seems impossble to fix

Tags: lua

```
 local move = game.StarterGui.BottmRight.Hotbar
 local moves = false

 script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:connect(function()
 if moves == false then
 move:TweenPosition{UDim2.new{0.724,0,0.919,0},"In", "Bounce", 2}
 moves = true
 wait(2)
 move.Visible = true

 else
 move:TweenPosition{UDim2.new{0.912,0,0.919,0},"Out", "Quint", 2}
 moves = false
 move.Visible = false
```

the error is:

```
Error:(28,1) Expected'end'(to close 'else' at line 11),got <eof>
```

Any idea?

Comment: The error message is clear enough, isn't it?

Comment: If you use indentation, errors like this will be easier to see.

Answer (score 1):

You need an "end" to close the else block of your conditional. Try putting "end)" as the last line... as you also need to close out of the `:connect` method

Answer (score 1):

You need two `end` statements (to close `if ... else` and to close `function()`) and also closing `)` for the `connect` method. As the result, you need to add `end end)` to fix the error.